# Clear Interval on hover React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use clearInterval when hovering over one of the slides but it doesn't seem to be doing anything and I can't figure out why.

Unfortunately all the previous examples I can find are in es5 and I find those difficult to understand

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KmWiawYnD97xCbZYENG

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

const Bg = styled.div`
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: papayawhip;
`

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            tabId: 1
        }
        this.handleActive = this.handleActive.bind(this)
        this.isShown = this.isShown.bind(this)
        this.nextSlide = this.nextSlide.bind(this)
        this.pause = this.pause.bind(this)
    }

    handleActive(id) {
        this.setState({
            tabId: id
        })
    }

    isShown(num) {
        return this.state.tabId === num
    }

    nextSlide() {
        this.setState({
            tabId: this.state.tabId + 1 < 5 || 0 ?  this.state.tabId + 1 : 1
        })
    }

    pause() {
        clearInterval(()=>this.interval)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const interval = setInterval(()=> this.nextSlide(),1000)
        this.setState({interval: interval})
    }

    render() {
        const data = [
            { id: 1, link: '', mob: '', slide: 'Slide 1', text: 'Slide 1' },
            { id: 2, link: '', mob: '', slide: 'Slide 2', text: 'Slide 2' },
            { id: 3, link: '', mob: '', slide: 'Slide 3', text: 'Slide 3' },
            { id: 4, link: '', mob: '', slide: 'Slide 4', text: 'Slide 4' },
            { id: 5, link: '', mob: '', slide: 'Slide 5', text: 'Slide 5' }
        ]

        const dataLength = data.length 
        return(
            <div >
                {console.log(dataLength)}
                {console.log(this.state.interval)}
                <Bg onMouseEnter={()=>this.pause()}>
                    {
                        data.map(item =>
                            <div>
                            {
                                this.isShown(item.id) &&
                                <div >{item.slide}</div>
                            }
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                </Bg>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.tabId}
                    {
                        data.map(item =>
                            <li key={item.id} onMouseEnter={() => this.handleActive(item.id)} >
                                {item.text}
                            </li>
                        )
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) accepts the result of `setInterval` which you had added to the component state in `componentDidMount`.

```
pause() {
  clearInterval(this.state.interval);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding the interval to my state

```
constructor() {
super()
this.state = {
  tabId: 1,
  interval: '',
 }  
}

handleActive = id => {
this.setState({
  tabId: id,
})
}

isShown = num => {
  return this.state.tabId === num
}

nextSlide = () => {
this.setState({
  tabId: this.state.tabId + 1 < 5 || 0 ? this.state.tabId + 1 : 1,
})
}

handlePause = () => {
this.interval = clearInterval(this.state.interval)
this.setState({ interval: this.interval })
}

handleStart = () => {
this.interval = setInterval(() => this.nextSlide(), 3000)
this.setState({ interval: this.interval })
}

componentDidMount = () => {
this.handleStart()
this.setState({ interval: this.interval })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`clearInterval` accepts handler, not a `function`

so instead of

```
clearInterval(()=>this.interval)
```

you should do

```
clearInterval(this.state.interval)
```

also, instead of

```
const interval = setInterval(()=> this.nextSlide(),1000)
```

you could simply write

```
const interval = setInterval(this.nextSlide,1000)
```

Comment: const interval = setInterval(this.nextSlide,1000) doesn't work for me but I've solved this thanks!